# remove duplicate fields in unix with vim

Tags: unix, vim

If I have the following format in vi but for hundreds of categories and thousands of items:

```
    Category1
    item
    Category1
    item
    Category1
    item
    Category2
    item
    Category2
    item
    Category2
    item
```

Is there any way in vi to end up like so:

```
    Category1
    item
    item
    item
    Category2
    item
    item
    item
```

I need to remove all instances of category except the first one. I need to keep all items.
I have tried supplementing and global changes but have not had any luck. Help would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Does a *Category* always contain the word *Category*? Does an *item* always contain the word *item*? How do we know what's a Category and what's an item?

Comment: My apologies. No, Category can be totally random from Computing to Baby Products. Item is usually a sub-category of the Category. I just wondered if there was a straight forward fix for the format supplied.

Comment: I just need one instance of the Category but for all items to remain. I cant use sort as the order is already as it needs to be. I just need to remove the duplicate Category fields except their first instance.

Comment: How do you recognize categories and items?

Comment: It is all raw data from xml that i have scraped using java and then got into its current state with vim. At the moment all categories are followed by an =

Comment: This would be trivial in awk.  That said, as others have seen your example needs help.  For example, "item" is not something that ends in a digit? Or Category always appears in a "category object"?  There needs to be a definitive way to tell them apart.  Then we can help you.  And unless there a major requirement for vi or vim, consider other tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming  = is there at the end of category lines....

Save the file to (for example) foo.txt  Use nawk on Solaris, not awk.

```
awk '/=$/ && !arr[$0]++ {print; next}  {print $0} ' foo.txt > newfile.txt
```

Sorry. I do not have a clear idea how to do this in vi/vim without massive typing efforts or using a complex ed file.  Someone else may have an idea.  If you are totally stuck, try the above.

Comment: You can pipe the thing to awk from inside vim using `%!awk ...` (Some additional escaping maybe needed)

Comment: Thank you for the help, my apologies for not being more specific in my questioning! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) has (among others) a `:DeleteDuplicateLinesOf` command. Assuming the categories can be detected by a trailing `=` (as you've indicated in the comments), this command will do:

```
:DeleteDuplicateLinesOf /=$/
```

Like @jimmcnamara's `awk` solution, this still assumes that identical categories all appear sequentially in the file; i.e. it doesn't shift around the items, just deleted the duplicate category lines.